# (Matplotlib) How to remove ticks and add label to multiple layers in a complex bar plot (with multiple broken axis)

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib

I have some data that I need to plot in a single bar graph, but since there are some outliers, I need to break the y axis twice in order to fit it nicely in a single plot.

So far, I tried to follow the instructions [here](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/broken_axis.html) but I am having trouble to remove the ticks for the "inside" part of the graph, as also to display the ylabel for some of the data and to fit the xlabel inside the image.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib2tikz import save as tikzsave

N = 5
ind = np.arange(N)
width = 0.27

fig = plt.figure()

f, (ax, ax2, ax3) = plt.subplots(3, 1, sharex=True)

yvals = [15, 15, 15, 14, 176]
rects11 = ax.bar(ind, yvals, width, color='r')
rects12 = ax2.bar(ind, yvals, width, color='r')
rects13 = ax3.bar(ind, yvals, width, color='r')

zvals = [146, 269, 269, 221, 21830]
rects21 = ax3.bar(ind+width, zvals, width, color='g')
rects22 = ax2.bar(ind+width, zvals, width, color='g')
rects23 = ax.bar(ind+width, zvals, width, color='g')

kvals = [390, 620, 620, 559, 134720]
rects31 = ax3.bar(ind+2*width, kvals, width, color='b')
rects32 = ax2.bar(ind+2*width, kvals, width, color='b')
rects33 = ax.bar(ind+width*2, kvals, width, color='b')

ax.set_ylim(134500, 135200)  # outliers 1
ax2.set_ylim(21500, 22200)  # outlier 2
ax3.set_ylim(0, 700)  # most of the data

ax3.spines['top'].set_visible(False)
ax3.tick_params(labeltop=False)

ax2.spines['top'].set_visible(False)
ax2.spines['bottom'].set_visible(False)
ax2.tick_params(labeltop=False)
ax2.tick_params(labelbottom=False)

ax.spines['top'].set_visible(False)
ax.spines['bottom'].set_visible(False)
ax.tick_params(labeltop='off')
ax.tick_params(labelbottom='off')

d = .015  # how big to make the diagonal lines in axes coordinates
kwargs = dict(transform=ax.transAxes, color='k', clip_on=False)
ax.plot((-d, +d), (-d, +d), **kwargs)
ax.plot((1 - d, 1 + d), (-d, +d), **kwargs)

kwargs.update(transform=ax2.transAxes)
ax2.plot((-d, +d), (1 - d, 1 + d), **kwargs)
ax2.plot((1 - d, 1 + d), (1 - d, 1 + d), **kwargs)

kwargs = dict(transform=ax2.transAxes, color='k', clip_on=False)
ax.plot((-d, +d), (-d, +d), **kwargs)
ax.plot((1 - d, 1 + d), (-d, +d), **kwargs)

kwargs.update(transform=ax3.transAxes)
ax2.plot((-d, +d), (1 - d, 1 + d), **kwargs)
ax2.plot((1 - d, 1 + d), (1 - d, 1 + d), **kwargs)

ax2.set_ylabel('YLABEL')

ax.set_xticks([])
ax2.set_xticks([])
ax3.set_xticks(ind+width)
ax3.set_xticklabels( ('SMALLNAME1', 'SMALLNAME2', 'SMALLNAME3', 'BIGNAME1\nTWOLINES', 'BIGNAME2\n3LINES\nANOTHERLINE'), rotation=45, ha='right' )
ax2.legend( (rects12[0], rects22[0], rects32[0]), ('Type1', 'Type2', 'Type3') )

def autolabel(rects):
    for rect in rects:
        h = rect.get_height()
        ax3.text(rect.get_x()+rect.get_width()/2., 1.05*h, '%d'%int(h), ha='center', va='bottom')
        ax2.text(rect.get_x()+rect.get_width()/2., 1.05*h, '%d'%int(h), ha='center', va='bottom')
        ax.text(rect.get_x()+rect.get_width()/2., 1.05*h, '%d'%int(h), ha='center', va='bottom')

rectsArray = [rects11, rects12, rects13,
              rects21, rects22, rects23,
              rects31, rects32, rects33]

for r in rectsArray:
    autolabel(r)

tikzsave("testplot.tex")

plt.show()
```

From the plot below, I think I am almost there, as we can see in the produced figure:
[image]

However, I am having trouble to:

1. Remove the tick marks in the middle and top cut
2. Make the xlabels appear entirely on the image
3. Display the y value on top of each bar (it worked well just for the bottom)

For 1. I tried to change the plt.margins but no luck so far.

To finish, I am unsure why some of the diagonal cuts in the y axis does not display entirely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution:

- 1. By using `ax.set_xticks([])` you can disable your ticks in your x-axis but first you have to remove the `sharex=True` from your subplots definition
- 2. I used the following piece of code, which among other things, it rotates you x-ticks `f.autofmt_xdate()`
- 3. There error here was the way you defined the y-position of your text. Using `1.05*h`, would be generally fine but here you have quite a big variance of values, therefore, for large values of `h`, the y-position of the text, would *shoot up* and it would not be visible. The fix was just using `h` as the y-position.

Also I would suggest to maybe resize the **text** with the `size=8`, or any number that you see fit. As far as to why some of your axis discontinuities appear half, I am not sure I have an answer, maybe it has to do with the fact that you turn off your axis and that interferes with the animation.

### Image Output:

[image]

### Complete Code:

The altered code is marked by comments:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib2tikz import save as tikzsave

N = 5
ind = np.arange(N)
width = 0.27

# fig = plt.figure()    # code removed

f, (ax, ax2, ax3) = plt.subplots(3, 1)

yvals = [15, 15, 15, 14, 176]
rects11 = ax.bar(ind, yvals, width, color='r')
rects12 = ax2.bar(ind, yvals, width, color='r')
rects13 = ax3.bar(ind, yvals, width, color='r')

zvals = [146, 269, 269, 221, 21830]
rects21 = ax3.bar(ind+width, zvals, width, color='g')
rects22 = ax2.bar(ind+width, zvals, width, color='g')
rects23 = ax.bar(ind+width, zvals, width, color='g')

kvals = [390, 620, 620, 559, 134720]
rects31 = ax3.bar(ind+2*width, kvals, width, color='b')
rects32 = ax2.bar(ind+2*width, kvals, width, color='b')
rects33 = ax.bar(ind+width*2, kvals, width, color='b')

ax2.set_xticks([])  # code added
ax.set_xticks([])   # code added

ax.set_ylim(134500, 135200)  # outliers 1
ax2.set_ylim(21500, 22200)  # outlier 2
ax3.set_ylim(0, 700)  # most of the data

ax3.spines['top'].set_visible(False)
ax3.tick_params(labeltop=False)
#
ax2.spines['top'].set_visible(False)
ax2.spines['bottom'].set_visible(False)
ax2.tick_params(labeltop=False)
ax2.tick_params(labelbottom=False)

ax.spines['top'].set_visible(False)
ax.spines['bottom'].set_visible(False)
ax.tick_params(labeltop='off')
ax.tick_params(labelbottom='off')

d = .015  # how big to make the diagonal lines in axes coordinates
kwargs = dict(transform=ax.transAxes, color='k', clip_on=False)
ax.plot((-d, +d), (-d, +d), **kwargs)
ax.plot((1 - d, 1 + d), (-d, +d), **kwargs)

kwargs.update(transform=ax2.transAxes)
ax2.plot((-d, +d), (1 - d, 1 + d), **kwargs)
ax2.plot((1 - d, 1 + d), (1 - d, 1 + d), **kwargs)

kwargs = dict(transform=ax2.transAxes, color='k', clip_on=False)
ax.plot((-d, +d), (-d, +d), **kwargs)
ax.plot((1 - d, 1 + d), (-d, +d), **kwargs)

kwargs.update(transform=ax3.transAxes)
ax2.plot((-d, +d), (1 - d, 1 + d), **kwargs)
ax2.plot((1 - d, 1 + d), (1 - d, 1 + d), **kwargs)

ax2.set_ylabel('YLABEL')

ax.set_xticks([])
ax2.set_xticks([])
ax3.set_xticks(ind+width)
ax3.set_xticklabels( ('SMALLNAME1', 'SMALLNAME2', 'SMALLNAME3', 'BIGNAME1\nTWOLINES', 'BIGNAME2\n3LINES\nANOTHERLINE'), ha='right')
ax2.legend((rects12[0], rects22[0], rects32[0]), ('Type1', 'Type2', 'Type3'))
f.autofmt_xdate()   # code added

def autolabel(rects):
    for rect in rects:
        h = rect.get_height()
        ax3.text(rect.get_x()+rect.get_width()/2., h, '%d'%int(h), ha='center', va='bottom')    # height altered
        ax2.text(rect.get_x()+rect.get_width()/2., h, '%d'%int(h), ha='center', va='bottom')
        ax.text(rect.get_x()+rect.get_width()/2., h, '%d'%int(h), ha='center', va='bottom')

rectsArray = [rects11, rects12, rects13,
              rects21, rects22, rects23,
              rects31, rects32, rects33]

for r in rectsArray:
    autolabel(r)

tikzsave("testplot.tex")

plt.show()
```